# JQUERY AJAX find filename in response data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hello im trying to load all file names from a folder.

im using this script and it returns a response object called data. When i use console.log on data it returns me to html below. how can i now collect all the file names out of there and write it into the variable fileNames?

my script:

```
var fileNames= "";
var folder = "csvData/";
    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url:  folder, 

          success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
          },
          async:false
      });
```

html inside of data response:
a the bottom you can see that a function is called for each file in the folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html dir="ltr" lang="de">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">

<script>
function addRow(name, url, isdir,
    size, size_string, date_modified, date_modified_string) {
  if (name == "." || name == "..")
    return;

  var root = document.location.pathname;
  if (root.substr(-1) !== "/")
    root += "/";

  var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var file_cell = document.createElement("td");
  var link = document.createElement("a");

  link.className = isdir ? "icon dir" : "icon file";

  if (isdir) {
    name = name + "/";
    url = url + "/";
    size = 0;
    size_string = "";
  } else {
    link.draggable = "true";
    link.addEventListener("dragstart", onDragStart, false);
  }
  link.innerText = name;
  link.href = root + url;

  file_cell.dataset.value = name;
  file_cell.appendChild(link);

  row.appendChild(file_cell);
  row.appendChild(createCell(size, size_string));
  row.appendChild(createCell(date_modified, date_modified_string));

  tbody.appendChild(row);
}

function onDragStart(e) {
  var el = e.srcElement;
  var name = el.innerText.replace(":", "");
  var download_url_data = "application/octet-stream:" + name + ":" + el.href;
  e.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", download_url_data);
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
}

function createCell(value, text) {
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.setAttribute("class", "detailsColumn");
  cell.dataset.value = value;
  cell.innerText = text;
  return cell;
}

function start(location) {
  var header = document.getElementById("header");
  header.innerText = header.innerText.replace("LOCATION", location);

  document.getElementById("title").innerText = header.innerText;
}

function onHasParentDirectory() {
  var box = document.getElementById("parentDirLinkBox");
  box.style.display = "block";

  var root = document.location.pathname;
  if (!root.endsWith("/"))
    root += "/";

  var link = document.getElementById("parentDirLink");
  link.href = root + "..";
}

function sortTable(column) {
  var theader = document.getElementById("theader");
  var oldOrder = theader.cells[column].dataset.order || '1';
  oldOrder = parseInt(oldOrder, 10)
  var newOrder = 0 - oldOrder;
  theader.cells[column].dataset.order = newOrder;

  var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
  var rows = tbody.rows;
  var list = [], i;
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    list.push(rows[i]);
  }

  list.sort(function(row1, row2) {
    var a = row1.cells[column].dataset.value;
    var b = row2.cells[column].dataset.value;
    if (column) {
      a = parseInt(a, 10);
      b = parseInt(b, 10);
      return a > b ? newOrder : a < b ? oldOrder : 0;
    }

    // Column 0 is text.
    if (a > b)
      return newOrder;
    if (a < b)
      return oldOrder;
    return 0;
  });

  // Appending an existing child again just moves it.
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    tbody.appendChild(list[i]);
  }
}

// Add event handlers to column headers.
function addHandlers(element, column) {
  element.onclick = (e) => sortTable(column);
  element.onkeydown = (e) => {
    if (e.key == 'Enter' || e.key == ' ') {
      sortTable(column);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
}

function onLoad() {
  addHandlers(document.getElementById('nameColumnHeader'), 0);
  addHandlers(document.getElementById('sizeColumnHeader'), 1);
  addHandlers(document.getElementById('dateColumnHeader'), 2);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onLoad);
</script>

<style>

  h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  th {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  td.detailsColumn {
    padding-inline-start: 2em;
    text-align: end;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  a.icon {
    padding-inline-start: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    user-select: auto;
  }

  a.icon:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  a.file {
    background : url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAABnRSTlMAAAAAAABupgeRAAABEElEQVR42nRRx3HDMBC846AHZ7sP54BmWAyrsP588qnwlhqw/k4v5ZwWxM1hzmGRgV1cYqrRarXoH2w2m6qqiqKIR6cPtzc3xMSML2Te7XZZlnW7Pe/91/dX47WRBHuA9oyGmRknzGDjab1ePzw8bLfb6WRalmW4ip9FDVpYSWZgOp12Oh3nXJ7nxoJSGEciteP9y+fH52q1euv38WosqA6T2gGOT44vry7BEQtJkMAMMpa6JagAMcUfWYa4hkkzAc7fFlSjwqCoOUYAF5RjHZPVCFBOtSBGfgUDji3c3jpibeEMQhIMh8NwshqyRsBJgvF4jMs/YlVR5KhgNpuBLzk0OcUiR3CMhcPaOzsZiAAA/AjmaB3WZIkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") left top no-repeat;
  }

  a.dir {
    background : url("data:image/png;base64,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") left top no-repeat;
  }

  a.up {
    background : url("data:image/png;base64,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") left top no-repeat;
  }

  html[dir=rtl] a {
    background-position-x: right;
  }

  #parentDirLinkBox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
</style>

<title id="title"></title>

</head>

<body>

<h1 id="header">Index von LOCATION</h1>

<div id="parentDirLinkBox" style="display:none">
  <a id="parentDirLink" class="icon up">
    <span id="parentDirText">[übergeordnetes Verzeichnis]</span>
  </a>
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header" id="theader">
      <th id="nameColumnHeader" tabindex=0 role="button">Name</th>
      <th id="sizeColumnHeader" class="detailsColumn" tabindex=0 role="button">
        Größe
      </th>
      <th id="dateColumnHeader" class="detailsColumn" tabindex=0 role="button">
        Änderungsdatum
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>

</html>
<script>// Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

/**
 * @fileoverview This file defines a singleton which provides access to all data
 * that is available as soon as the page's resources are loaded (before DOM
 * content has finished loading). This data includes both localized strings and
 * any data that is important to have ready from a very early stage (e.g. things
 * that must be displayed right away).
 *
 * Note that loadTimeData is not guaranteed to be consistent between page
 * refreshes (https://crbug.com/740629) and should not contain values that might
 * change if the page is re-opened later.
 */

/** @type {!LoadTimeData} */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-var
var loadTimeData;

class LoadTimeData {
  constructor() {
    /** @type {?Object} */
    this.data_ = null;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the backing object.
   *
   * Note that there is no getter for |data_| to discourage abuse of the form:
   *
   *     var value = loadTimeData.data()['key'];
   *
   * @param {Object} value The de-serialized page data.
   */
  set data(value) {
    expect(!this.data_, 'Re-setting data.');
    this.data_ = value;
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} id An ID of a value that might exist.
   * @return {boolean} True if |id| is a key in the dictionary.
   */
  valueExists(id) {
    return id in this.data_;
  }

  /**
   * Fetches a value, expecting that it exists.
   * @param {string} id The key that identifies the desired value.
   * @return {*} The corresponding value.
   */
  getValue(id) {
    expect(this.data_, 'No data. Did you remember to include strings.js?');
    const value = this.data_[id];
    expect(typeof value !== 'undefined', 'Could not find value for ' + id);
    return value;
  }

  /**
   * As above, but also makes sure that the value is a string.
   * @param {string} id The key that identifies the desired string.
   * @return {string} The corresponding string value.
   */
  getString(id) {
    const value = this.getValue(id);
    expectIsType(id, value, 'string');
    return /** @type {string} */ (value);
  }

  /**
   * Returns a formatted localized string where $1 to $9 are replaced by the
   * second to the tenth argument.
   * @param {string} id The ID of the string we want.
   * @param {...(string|number)} var_args The extra values to include in the
   *     formatted output.
   * @return {string} The formatted string.
   */
  getStringF(id, var_args) {
    const value = this.getString(id);
    if (!value) {
      return '';
    }

    const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args[0] = value;
    return this.substituteString.apply(this, args);
  }

  /**
   * Returns a formatted localized string where $1 to $9 are replaced by the
   * second to the tenth argument. Any standalone $ signs must be escaped as
   * $$.
   * @param {string} label The label to substitute through.
   *     This is not an resource ID.
   * @param {...(string|number)} var_args The extra values to include in the
   *     formatted output.
   * @return {string} The formatted string.
   */
  substituteString(label, var_args) {
    const varArgs = arguments;
    return label.replace(/\$(.|$|\n)/g, function(m) {
      expect(m.match(/\$[$1-9]/), 'Unescaped $ found in localized string.');
      return m === '$$' ? '$' : varArgs[m[1]];
    });
  }

  /**
   * Returns a formatted string where $1 to $9 are replaced by the second to
   * tenth argument, split apart into a list of pieces describing how the
   * substitution was performed. Any standalone $ signs must be escaped as $$.
   * @param {string} label A localized string to substitute through.
   *     This is not an resource ID.
   * @param {...(string|number)} var_args The extra values to include in the
   *     formatted output.
   * @return {!Array<!{value: string, arg: (null|string)}>} The formatted
   *     string pieces.
   */
  getSubstitutedStringPieces(label, var_args) {
    const varArgs = arguments;
    // Split the string by separately matching all occurrences of $1-9 and of
    // non $1-9 pieces.
    const pieces = (label.match(/(\$[1-9])|(([^$]|\$([^1-9]|$))+)/g) ||
                    []).map(function(p) {
      // Pieces that are not $1-9 should be returned after replacing $$
      // with $.
      if (!p.match(/^\$[1-9]$/)) {
        expect(
            (p.match(/\$/g) || []).length % 2 === 0,
            'Unescaped $ found in localized string.');
        return {value: p.replace(/\$\$/g, '$'), arg: null};
      }

      // Otherwise, return the substitution value.
      return {value: varArgs[p[1]], arg: p};
    });

    return pieces;
  }

  /**
   * As above, but also makes sure that the value is a boolean.
   * @param {string} id The key that identifies the desired boolean.
   * @return {boolean} The corresponding boolean value.
   */
  getBoolean(id) {
    const value = this.getValue(id);
    expectIsType(id, value, 'boolean');
    return /** @type {boolean} */ (value);
  }

  /**
   * As above, but also makes sure that the value is an integer.
   * @param {string} id The key that identifies the desired number.
   * @return {number} The corresponding number value.
   */
  getInteger(id) {
    const value = this.getValue(id);
    expectIsType(id, value, 'number');
    expect(value === Math.floor(value), 'Number isn\'t integer: ' + value);
    return /** @type {number} */ (value);
  }

  /**
   * Override values in loadTimeData with the values found in |replacements|.
   * @param {Object} replacements The dictionary object of keys to replace.
   */
  overrideValues(replacements) {
    expect(
        typeof replacements === 'object',
        'Replacements must be a dictionary object.');
    for (const key in replacements) {
      this.data_[key] = replacements[key];
    }
  }

  /**
   * Reset loadTimeData's data. Should only be used in tests.
   * @param {?Object} newData The data to restore to, when null restores to
   *    unset state.
   */
  resetForTesting(newData = null) {
    this.data_ = newData;
  }

  /**
   * @return {boolean} Whether loadTimeData.data has been set.
   */
  isInitialized() {
    return this.data_ !== null;
  }
}

  /**
   * Checks condition, throws error message if expectation fails.
   * @param {*} condition The condition to check for truthiness.
   * @param {string} message The message to display if the check fails.
   */
  function expect(condition, message) {
    if (!condition) {
      throw new Error(
          'Unexpected condition on ' + document.location.href + ': ' + message);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Checks that the given value has the given type.
   * @param {string} id The id of the value (only used for error message).
   * @param {*} value The value to check the type on.
   * @param {string} type The type we expect |value| to be.
   */
  function expectIsType(id, value, type) {
    expect(
        typeof value === type, '[' + value + '] (' + id + ') is not a ' + type);
  }

  expect(!loadTimeData, 'should only include this file once');
  loadTimeData = new LoadTimeData;

  // Expose |loadTimeData| directly on |window|, since within a JS module the
  // scope is local and not all files have been updated to import the exported
  // |loadTimeData| explicitly.
  window.loadTimeData = loadTimeData;

  console.warn('crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.');</script><script>loadTimeData.data = {"header":"Index von LOCATION","headerDateModified":"Änderungsdatum","headerName":"Name","headerSize":"Größe","language":"de","parentDirText":"[übergeordnetes Verzeichnis]","textdirection":"ltr"};</script><script>start("C:\\Users\\MYNAME-\\eclipse-workspace\\htmlCsvtable\\src\\htmlTableGeneration\\csvData\\");</script>
<script>onHasParentDirectory();</script>
<script>addRow("20220201221359.csv","20220201221359.csv",0,2959,"2.9 kB",1644181136,"06.02.22, 21:58:56");</script>
<script>addRow("20220206091030.csv","20220206091030.csv",0,2958,"2.9 kB",1644181136,"06.02.22, 21:58:56");</script>
<script>addRow("20220206135359.csv","20220206135359.csv",0,2959,"2.9 kB",1644181136,"06.02.22, 21:58:56");</script>
```

Comment: You should call a controller script that returns structured data like JSON, not try to parse the directory listing from the webserver.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean with controller script?

Comment: Normally you send AJAX requests to a script, not a static URL.

Comment: Never ever use `async:false`. It is a horrible practice and has been deprecated by browser vendors for a few years now

Comment: Are you trying to run code inside of the returned file?

Comment: @TonyM no, i just want to get the file names out of there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to extract the file names from the calls to addRow.

Here's an example of how to extract them using a regular expression.

```js
const findFiles = (text) => {
  let matches = [];
  let match;
  let regex = /addRow\("(.*?)"/g;

  while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
  }
  return matches;
};

// instead of this example "text" use the result from your AJAX call
const text = `<script>onHasParentDirectory();</scri` + `pt><script>addRow("20220201221359.csv","20220201221359.csv",0,2959,"2.9 kB",1644181136,"06.02.22, 21:58:56");</scri` + `pt><script>addRow("20220206091030.csv","20220206091030.csv",0,2958,"2.9 kB",1644181136,"06.02.22, 21:58:56");</scri` + `pt><scri` + `pt>addRow("20220206135359.csv","20220206135359.csv",0,2959,"2.9 kB",1644181136,"06.02.22, 21:58:56");</scri` + `pt>`;

console.log(findFiles(text));
```

Comment: this helped me so much thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you can just `load` the file and convert the response to a jQuery object. This gives you the ability to use jQuery's DOM traversal functions like `$.find()` etc.

```js
$("#test").load( "csvData/", function(data) {
  console.log($(data));
  // $(data).find("#someselector")
  // or use the regex answer here findFiles(data)
})
```

The ID test is just a container to place results in or something like that.